# javascript page navigation error in firefox

Tags: javascript

i use this javscript function for show page navigation

```
<script>
function parseNum(number, val){
number = parseInt(number);
number = number + val;
return (number < 10 ? '0' : '') + number;
}
function next()
{
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("in-page").innerHTML) < parseInt(document.getElementById("t-page").innerHTML))
{
var iid=document.getElementById("in-page").innerHTML;
var id=document.getElementById("in-page").innerHTML;
var realid=document.getElementById("r-page").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("in-page").innerHTML=parseNum(id, 1);
if(parseInt(document.getElementById("flag").innerHTML)=='0')
{
document.getElementById("r-page").innerHTML=parseNum(realid, 1);
}
else if(document.getElementById("flag").innerHTML=='1')
{
document.getElementById("r-page").innerHTML=parseNum(realid, 1);
document.getElementById("flag").innerHTML='0';
}
}
}
</script>

<span id="flag" style="display:none">0</span><span id="prev" onclick=prev();>
<<
</span><span id="r-page" style="display:none" >0</span>  |  <span id="next" style=cursor:pointer; onclick=next();>
>>
</span><br/><br/><span id="in-page">01</span><span >of</span><span id="t-page">12</span>
```

when click in next work good . but when number is 08 and click next in-page jump to 01 and no 09 . for all test this result same . this error happend only in firfox and safari and in chrome and ie work fine .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
number = parseInt(number);
```

to

```
number = parseInt(number, 10);
```

because on Firefox (and in old versions of other browsers, numbers starting with a `"0"` are parsed as octal, and the parsing stops at the first out of range characters, which lets only `"0"` when you're parsing `"08"` or `"09"`.

Comment: +1, good practice to specify on which base the parse must be done

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the base in parseInt because 08 is recognised as an octal number.

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

In any case, it is safer to always specify the base.